# AWS route53 hosted zone settings

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I have registered a domain name on AWS route53. The domain name is invatxxx.com
I have an ec2 instance, on that machine an apache server and Drupal web site. The ec2 instance has an elastic ip address xx.xx.66.245. I can access the website from the IP address. 
The domain has the following server names:

- ns-xx.awsdns-xx.net
- ns-x5.awsdns-x1.com
- ns-x3.awsdns-x2.co.uk
- ns-xx1.awsdns-x3.org

I have created a hosted zone with a name as the domain name, to '**NS – Name server**' record set I added the server names from the registered domain. 
To '**SOA – Start of authority**' record set i added the '

> ns-xx1.awsdns-x3.org. awsdns-hostmaster.amazon.com. 1 7200 900 1209600
>   86400

' at value.
for '**A - ipv4 address**' record setI added the 'www' before the domain name and for value the elastic IP address of the instance.
I had another domain name for this instance and it worked, I also added SSL certificate from https://letsencrypt.org/ for the old domain name. But when I tried to change the domain name it did not work. 
[image]
Any ideas what it is wrong with my settings?

Comment: You current have no 'A' records defined for either the www or the non-www site.  Get that working before worrying about anything else.  See also [this link](http://dig-nslookup.nmonitoring.com/dns-dig-nslookup.html?domain=invatait.com&pingsub=1)

Comment: Why did you modify the SOA record? If you get this wrong, nothing will work. You should put it back as it was. The SOA is created by Route 53 when you register (meaning purchase) or transfer a domain name. The only time that you should change this is for delegating the domain to another DNS server. For web servers, etc. you need to create an 'A' or 'CNAME' record. Note: If you change the SOA, also increment the serial number field.

Comment: I deleted the hosted zone that was created by the Route 53, now I am trying to restore it, I observed that SOA record is one of the server names from the registered domain, but I did not know which one. I created the A record for www site and put the Elastic IP address.

Comment: maybe I need to create a new hosted zone and copy the server names to the registered domain?

Comment: It isn't possible to "restore" a hosted zone -- you can't create a new hosted zone that is identical to one you deleted.  You cannot edit the NS or SOA records and have a working hosted zone.  Use the default values for the new zone and update the authoritative name servers to the new values with your registrar.  https://stackoverflow.com/q/43660375/1695906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a hosted zone -- an SOA record and an NS record are created by default; do not edit them.
Now you must first add an A record for your domain 'invatxxx.com' before adding any more A record for any other hostname. See the screenshot below and note that **you must leave the "Name" field blank** (you will find it automatically ending with uneditable text invatxxx.com):

[image]

At this point your website should be accessible at http://invatxxx.com/.
In case you want your website to be available at http://www.invatxxx.com/ also, then add a CNAME record to make 'www.invatxxx.com' an alias of 'invatxxx.com'. See the screenshot below and note that **you must not leave the "Name" field blank this time** and that "Value" field should be filled with 'invatxxx.com':

[image]

At this point your website should be accessible at http://www.invatxxx.com/ as well.