# import Namecheap zone file to AWS Route53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

I'm trying to import a Namecheap zone file to Route53.

Here is the zone file:

```
   @    3601    IN SOA   parkingpage.namecheap.com.   example.gmail.com.   2018071000  86400 7200 3600000  3601
        @    3600   IN      NS   dns1.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      NS   dns2.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward1.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward2.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward3.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      MX  15  eforward4.registrar-servers.com.
        @    3600   IN      MX  20  eforward5.registrar-servers.com.
      www    1800   IN   CNAME   parkingpage.namecheap.com.
        @    3600   IN     TXT   v=spf1 include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com ~all
```

the error I get from Route53 is:

```
Error parsing zone file: Error in line 1: no owner (encountered after 0 correct records) In line: @ 3601 IN SOA parkingpage.namecheap.com.
```

I saw a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48531597/aws-route53-hosted-zone-settings) but it concerned GoDaddy and the error message was different.

Comment: I think you have to delete the SOA and the NS lines, to host your domain in route 53, cause it will use it&amp;#39;s own SOA and ns config

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two changes and I was able to successfully import:

- add `$ORIGIN www.example.com` on first line
- removed white space from start of each line

the final zone file looks like this

```
$ORIGIN www.example.com
@    3601    IN SOA   parkingpage.namecheap.com.   example.gmail.com.   2018071000  86400 7200 3600000  3601
@    3600   IN      NS   dns1.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      NS   dns2.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward1.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward2.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      MX  10  eforward3.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      MX  15  eforward4.registrar-servers.com.
@    3600   IN      MX  20  eforward5.registrar-servers.com.
www    1800   IN   CNAME   parkingpage.namecheap.com.
@    3600   IN     TXT   v=spf1 include:spf.efwd.registrar-servers.com ~all
```

Answer (score 0):

The NS and SOS are automatically created when you create the zone in Route 53.

Rather than import, just create the zone, then add the MX, TXT and CNAME records.