# Route53 hosted zone SERVFAIL on nslookup

Tags: dns, amazon-route53

I have looked at the DNS records a hundred times and everything seems fine. Maybe I'm just being impatient and it still needs to propagate?

These are the records I have
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CxLIv.jpg

Comment: No, this isn't a "propagation" issue.  About the NS and SOA records... are these the original values that Route 53 placed here when you created the hosted zone, or did you change them to these values?

Comment: I accidentally deleted the hosted zone that route53 created when I purchased the domain through amazon. I then copied the name servers that the domain registration was still set to into the new hosted zone that I created and recreated what I believe the SOA should be with a little guesswork. Is there a way to recreate the autogenerated hosted zone?

Comment: I suspected you had deleted it and tried to put it back. 
That's not really a valid thing to do.  Create a new hosted zone, don't change it at all, and instead go into Route 53 Domains and make the new one authoritative. https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669003/1695906

Comment: ah ok, thanks for the help! That's definitely my problem. I'm trying to learn terraform and I'm having trouble persisting my zone while still allowing destruction of my environment. Other people seem to have this use case as a problem for a long time now as shown in this thread https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/3874.
If you want to post an answer I'll close this question. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like what I was trying to do is called terraform data sources

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the mentioned Name Servers (NS records) to the domain registrar as Domain Name Servers. After that the DNS entries made in route53 would work.

Comment: The second picture in that imgur album shows the amazon registrar's DNS settings