# Trouble re-establishing Hosted Zone on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, nameservers

I bought domain through Route 53, which created hosted zone. I changed hosted zone to Linode including NS records. Site as working without incident for last 6 months.

48 hours ago, Linode deleted the DNS records. After a call 24 hours ago, they reinstated the hosted zone. The site, which was functioning until 48 hours ago, was being hosted on squarespace.

I have since deleted the zone in Linode and set up the CNAME, MX and A records correctly in AWS. However, whois still shows Linode as NS. If this the standard 24 hour propagation issue? Or is this an AWS issue because the original hosted zone was moved away to another provider.

The 24 hour propagation, since I deleted the Linode records this morning, might still be at play. In the event it is not, any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you change the name servers to point to your hosted zone?

Comment: Slightly different scenario, same solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43669003/1695906

Comment: Hey John, I am a bit uncertain about that step because when you purchase a domain it comes witgh the NS and SOA records as default. I am not sure what to change to. I am going to look at Michael's suggested link but I anticipate the "What name servers to I change to?" question coming up as part of the exercise. Will advise.

Comment: NS records changed. Waiting. Thank you!

Comment: Michael. it worked. Many thanks!