# AWS Certificate pending validation for S3 site

Tags: ssl-certificate, amazon-route53

Under `Route 53` I have registered a domain name `domain.name` and created a hosted zone which, by default, has the `NS` and `SOA` records.

In `Certificates` I have requested a public certificate for the domain name `domain.name` in the `us-east-1` region (N. Virginia).

Under the new certificate, I see the notice `Add the following CNAME record to your DNS configuration` and it has **name** `_1abc2cd5ac5ee12c1234f1234c123b1c.domain.name.` and **value** `_e8f2db123456789c2b1a1234ab123456.abcdefghij.acm-validations.aws.`

When, under the new `domain.name` certificate, I click `Request Record in Route 53` I see the `Success` message and this leads me to see the `CNAME` record under `Route 53` with **Record name** `_1abc2cd5ac5ee12c1234f1234c123b1c.domain.name` and **value** `_e8f2db123456789c2b1a1234ab123456.abcdefghij.acm-validations.aws.`

From this point on the certificate **status** persistently shows `Pending validation` (for >3 hours now.)

While I notice that the **name** property appears to have a trailing period on the certificate page, but does not have the trailing period on the record name, I cannot see anything else which would cause this to fail validation.

Comment: A colleague of mine is having issues with the same behavior today, maybe a more wide-spread issue in AWS?

Answer (score 1):

As described on this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43660375/deleted-route-53-hosted-zone-cant-correctly-create-it-again/43669003#43669003) the problem was that when I deleted and created a new hosted zone the DNS names were incorrect.

To solve this I copied the `Name servers` from under my `Registered domains` entry and updated the name server addresses for the `NS` record of my hosted zone.